# Javascript: finding out dates of specification change and adoption

Tags: javascript, specifications

Someone asked me when was **minimumFractionDigits** and **maximumFractionDigits** added to the **toLocalString** method. I am wondering, is there a way to find out the dates in which:

1. It was added to the specification
2. It was adopted by different browsers

It seems this is possible only for the whole method in sites like canIUser shown in  this [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=toLocaleString()). However if the implementation changes or options are added, how can one investigate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Specifications ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes! I stumbled upon it now, can one find out when those apis were added to the major browsers? Can a browser implement just parts of the specifications? especially with ones in draft state.

Comment: I Love the MDN site's docs (compared to w3schools or such), yet never noticed the specifications section